# how to find exact path of android external storage programatically at runtime?

Tags: android

```
mySound.load(new URLRequest("file://mnt/sdcard/AnyFolder/YourSound.mp3"));`<br/>
```

I want to detect the name of the sdcard at runtime, so i can store my app-data on external storage.

The above codeline is an example of storing a mp3 to user's required location.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are asking for:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
    "/" + "yourfilename");
```

I also recomend you to avoid writing to the root of the SD card.  It is a good practice to write your aplication data into the appropriate folder:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
    "/Android/data/com.example.testapp/" + "yourfilename");
```

Obviously, you have to change the "com.example.testapp" with your app package (the package you entered when you created the project in Eclipse/Android Studio).

Answer (score 0):

```
getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

in

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Answer (score 0):

use `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` it will give path to internal SD mount point like "/mnt/sdcard"

Answer (score 0):

First, on Android 4.4+, you do not have write access to removable media (e.g., "external SD"), except for any locations on that media that might be returned by

> getExternalFilesDirs() and getExternalCacheDirs().

See Dave Smith's excellent analysis of this, particularly if you want the low-level details.

Second, lest anyone quibble on whether or not removable media access is otherwise part of the Android SDK, here is [Dianne Hackborn's assessment](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/14VUiIgwUjY%5B101-125-false%5D):

...keep in mind: until Android 4.4, the official Android platform has not supported SD cards at all except for two special cases: the old school storage layout where external storage is an SD card (which is still supported by the platform today), and a small feature added to Android 3.0 where it would scan additional SD cards and add them to the media provider and give apps read-only access to their files (which is also still supported in the platform today).

> Android 4.4 is the first release of the platform that has actually
>   allowed applications to use SD cards for storage. Any access to them
>   prior to that was through private, unsupported APIs. We now have a
>   quite rich API in the platform that allows applications to make use of
>   SD cards in a supported way, in better ways than they have been able
>   to before: they can make free use of their app-specific storage area
>   without requiring any permissions in the app, and can access any other
>   files on the SD card as long as they go through the file picker, again
>   without needing any special permissions.